# C# Out of Range: Spawning textFile contents to listBoxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating an application would take textfile paths from a textfile, and then load them into a listbox, which when clicked on in listbox, the textfile content will spawn in a script editor widget called `textEditorControl1`.

The thing is. When I delete a thing from the listbox which hosts the textfile names, AND THEN, click on another item in listbox; it gives me an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative
>   and less than the size of the collection.

on `string fullFileName2 = selectedScripts[listBox3.SelectedIndex];`

```
    List<String> fullFileName;
    List<String> fullFileName2;
 List<string> selectedScripts = new List<string>();

        public void listBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (listBox3.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                string fullFileName2 = selectedScripts[listBox3.SelectedIndex];
                textBox3.Text = fullFileName2;
                string File1 = fullFileName2;
                string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(File1);
                textEditorControl1.Text = text;
                textEditorControl1.Refresh();
            }
            else
            {

            }

        private void materialFlatButton10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog OpenFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
            OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt|All Files|*.*|Lua Files|*.lua";
            OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Select a Text/Lua File";
            if (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                fullFileName2 = new List<String>(OpenFileDialog1.FileNames);


                foreach (string s in OpenFileDialog1.FileNames)
                {
                    listBox3.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(s));
                    selectedScripts.Add(s);
                }


            }
        }



private void deleteFromListToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label4.Text = " ";
        textBox3.Text = "";
        IDocument document = textEditorControl1.Document;
        document.Remove(0, document.TextLength);
        textEditorControl1.Refresh();
        selectedScripts.Clear();

        for (int i = listBox3.SelectedIndices.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            listBox3.Items.RemoveAt(listBox3.SelectedIndices[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're clearing SelectedScripts, and then when you click on something, you're trying to access an item in SelectedScripts at index listBox3.SelectedIndex, but at this point SelectedScripts is empty.

I think your delete method should be this:

```
private void deleteFromListToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label4.Text = " ";
    textBox3.Text = "";
    IDocument document = textEditorControl1.Document;
    document.Remove(0, document.TextLength);
    textEditorControl1.Refresh();

    for (int i = listBox3.SelectedIndices.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        selectedScripts.RemoveAt(listBox3.SelectedIndices[i]);
        listBox3.Items.RemoveAt(listBox3.SelectedIndices[i]);
    }
}
```

Note that the UI ListBox control can take classes, so you could encapsulate all of your data into one class object which you add to the list.

Comment: Oh, spawn the new text file contents from that option into the script editor.

Comment: @RohanPas I've added an answer which should hopefully resolve your situation.

See this video for how to use class objects in a list: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_leuGAsWDis

Comment: .OrderByDescending is not a trait of SelectedIndices though. Thanks for the video.

Comment: The thing is that it should not be empty, because I am adding their string to the array when they import the file

Comment: @RohanPas I've updated my answer to not use Linq. SelectedScripts, in your code, becomes empty because in the delete method you were calling `selectedScripts.Clear()` which deleted everything from SelectedScripts.